# Releasing the android app

Tags: android, google-play

This question is related to the releasing the app to app store.
I am getting this error in commend line.

error=   ERROR getting 'android:name' attribute: attribute is not an integer value

actually I am launching the app, but its showing the error in commend line.

**Edit**:

here is my **Manifest.xml** file code

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:name="mobile.briltime.brilnet.SdkDemoLowLevelApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" > 

    <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="mobile.briltime.brilnet.SplaseScreen" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="mobile.briltime.brilnet.MainActivity"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="mobile.briltime.brilnet.LoginManual"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name="mobile.briltime.brilnet.AnimationStackedFrames"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

     <activity android:name="mobile.briltime.brilnet.Login"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

      <activity android:name="mobile.briltime.brilnet.MyFriendListActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <provider
        android:name="com.c2call.sdk.pub.db.provider.C2CallContentProvider"
        android:authorities="mobile.briltime.brilnet.content"
        android:exported="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
        <grant-uri-permission android:pathPattern=".*" />
    </provider>   
</application>
```

Comment: Share your xml here...

Comment: Post your manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your contribution, finally i solved the problem. 
Simply I delete the screen orientation from the manifest file and now its working.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have your `android:name` attribute hardcoded. Change it to a string resource.

Example:

```
android:name = "MyAppName"
```

to

```
android:name = "@string/app_name"
```

with strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyAppName</string>
</resources>
```

I guessed this (you didn't give us enough information to do more) because the resource ids in Android are ints, generated by `aapt`.
More about the [Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) and [String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).
I don't know why that should be an issue to the Playstore though...

Comment: I define it inside the string file.